# Leaf Trees in Haskell - non-exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell

This function follows a path of Bools, going left or right depending on False or True, respectively

```
data LTree a = Leaf a 
             | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
             deriving (Show)

select :: LTree a -> [Bool] -> (Maybe a)
select (Fork (Leaf a) (Leaf b)) (l:ls)  = if l==False  then Just a 
                                                       else Just b
select (Fork l r) (b:bs) = if b==False  then select l bs
                                        else select r bs
```

The thing is, LTree does not have declared the Empty value, how can i know that it is a node or a fork that i am falling into with my function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Ask the compiler

GHC can warn you about non-exhaustive patterns at compile time instead of waiting to run time to discover them. If I put your code into a file and compile it with the [`-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html#idp10519744)

```
ghc -fwarn-incomplete-patterns nonExhaustiveLeafTree.hs
```

It produces the following error message:

```
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `select':
        Patterns not matched:
            (Leaf _) _
            (Fork (Fork _ _) _) []
            (Fork (Leaf _) (Fork _ _)) []
            (Fork (Leaf _) (Leaf _)) []
```

After adding the [rule you suggested in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016799/414413) to cover `[]`, it still produces a warning about anything where the tree is a `Leaf _`

```
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `select': Patterns not matched: (Leaf _) _
```

#### Covering everything

We can cover all of the patterns easily if we handle `Leaf`s and `Fork`s separately from each other. This also removes the duplicate code of deciding which way to go on a `Fork` when its direct descendants are leaves.

You'll know that there's a result when you reach a `Leaf` and there's no path left to follow.

```
select (Leaf a) [] = Just a
```

You'll need to decide what to do when you reach a `Leaf` and there's still a path you need to follow.

```
select (Leaf a) (l:ls) = ????
```

Like you mentioned in your answer, you'll know there's no result when there's no path left and you are at a `Fork`.

```
select (Fork _ _) [] = Nothing
```

You can simplify what happens when there's a fork and a path to a single rule.

```
select (Fork l r) (b:bs) = if b
                           then select r bs
                           else select l bs
```

Comment: Thank you for the insights Cirdec, i have a test tomorrow and i am a bit late on the study, your help is graceful :)

Comment: Use `:set -fwarn-incomplete-patterns` in GHCi, or simply `.set -Wall` for all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

this was straightforward, i need some rest i guess:

This was missing :

```
select (Fork l r) [] = Nothing
```