# Retrieve minimum from tree and the tree itself - haskell

Tags: haskell

With this function, i can remove the minimum in a binary search tree:

```
data BTree a = Empty
             | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)

semmin :: BTree a -> BTree a
semmin (Node x Empty Empty) = Empty
semmin (Node x l r) = Node x (semmin l) r
```

I want to retrieve the minimum value and the tree without this minimum, the trick is, i can traverse it only once.

```
The type is mimSmim :: BTree a -> (a,BTree a)
```

how should i do it?

EDIT:
Does this count as one traverse?

```
semmin :: BTree a -> (a,BTree a)
semmin (Node x Empty Empty) = (x,Empty)
semmin (Node x l r) = let i= (semmin l)
                       in (fst(i),(Node x (snd(i)) r))
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: not quite, i am studying to the final exam.

Comment: `semmin` has [non-exhaustive patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016867/414413).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: If you are at a `Node x l r` and you already knew that the left tree's `mimSmim l` was `(a, l')`, then the `Node`'s `mimSmim (Node x l r)` would be `(a, Node x l' r)`.

Comment: well.. does this count as one traverse?
check original post please*
Thank you very much for all the help you've been providing cirdec!

Comment: @skills, I don't know quite what you mean, but this is the best you can do. It will rebuild one path through the tree, and because it's lazy, that happens in one "pass".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `zipper`. A `[zipper][1]` is a representation of another data structure that lets you focus one section of the entire structure without losing the rest. Please see the last chapter of [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) for an intuitive approach to developing the `zipper` data type and functions to use on it.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is on the right track, even if not completely correct:

```
semmin :: BTree a -> (a,BTree a)
semmin (Node x Empty Empty) = (x,Empty)
semmin (Node x l r) = let i= (semmin l)
                       in (fst(i),(Node x (snd(i)) r))
```

As a hint for improving your code, not that the following crashes:

```
semmin (Node 1 Empty (Node 2 Empty Empty))
```

Also, to improve readability a bit, I would suggest:

```
semmin :: BTree a -> (a,BTree a)
semmin (Node x Empty Empty) = (x,Empty)
semmin (Node x l r) = let (minValue, minTree) = semmin l
                       in (minValue, Node x minTree r)
```

Finally, this looks as if it's returning the whole tree back, instead of the tree at which the minimum is found. Check if that's the case, and if that's what you want.